Python script using selenium to refresh webpage how to target button
I am trying to refresh a webpage until a button exists and is enabled, when it is I want to click it.
I am trying the following:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# Initializing the browser driver (for example, Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')

# Open the desired webpage
driver.get('https://www.example.com')

while True:
    try:
        # Find the button with the text "Buy"
        reserve_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Buy")]')
        
        # If the button is found, click on it
        reserve_button.click()
        print("The 'Buy' button is found and clicked.")
        break  # Exit the while loop if the button is found and clicked
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("The 'Buy' button could not be found on the webpage. Page is being refreshed...")
        
        # Refresh the page
        driver.refresh()

# Quit the browser driver
driver.quit()

But the button is not found. Here is a copy of the element when inspecting the page.
<div class="sc-bczRLJ hdBksE"><button disabled="" type="button" class="sc-eCYdqJ izberk">Buy</button></div>

How should I target the button?

Have you tried using WebDriverWait ?
